# Neo4j Desktop neosemantics RPC failure invoking rdf.preview.fetch - NoSuchMethodError JacksonFeatureSet JSONParser getReadCapabilities

Tags: neo4j, jackson, wikidata

I'm attempting to extract RDF from Wikidata into a Neo4j graph through the Neo4j Desktop with APOC and Neosemantics plugins on a Mac and keep getting Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed

`

```
Failed to invoke procedure `n10s.rdf.preview.fetch`: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeatureSet com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getReadCapabilities()'
```

`

Trying to run the following code:

`

```
WITH 'PREFIX neo: <neo4j://wiki#>
CONSTRUCT {
    ?descendant a neo:Entity .
    ?descendant neo:entityName ?descendantLabel .
    ?descendant neo:entityGender ?gender .
  }
WHERE
{
  VALUES ($ancestor) {(wd:Q317521)}
  ?ancestor wdt:P40? ?descendant.
  ?descendant wdt:P21 ?gender .
  ?descendant rdfs:label ?descendantLabel .
  FILTER (LANG(?descendantLabel) = "en") .
}' AS sparql
CALL n10s.rdf.preview.fetch(
  "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=" +  apoc.text.urlencode(sparql),
  "JSON-LD",  { headerParams: { Accept: "application/ld+json" } }
)
YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships
```

`

I use Homebrew for just about everything on my Mac and just completed a `brew upgrade`.  I use sdkman for Java and upgraded that as well.

I've tried to rollback to an earlier version of the Desktop as well as other versions of the plugins as well.  Here are the various software versions I'm using.

- Mac Monterey 12.6
- Neo4j Desktop 1.5.2
- APOC 4.4.0.6
- Neosemantics 4.4.0.1
- openjdk 17.0.5
- Python 3.10.8

Any suggestions?  Perhaps different versions of the JDK to get at the Jackson JSON Parser?

Comment: The [`getReadCapabilities`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#getReadCapabilities--) appears with jackson 13, you can check if this is the jackson version you are currently using.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I don't know how to check which version of jackson I'm using.  From that message, I don't think I'm using any version of jackson.   I was assuming this would be bundled into the JDK and even though I'm using openjdk 17.0.5, the Neo4j Desktop comes bundled with 11 and 8 so thought this would be included with either of them.  Going to RTFM at https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-json/jackson-installation.html and hopefully install via homebrew somehow.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have helped in some way, the only thing I can suggest is inspect the neo4j maven pom and check if there is the jackson 2.13 dependency and eventually add it and try again to build your project.

Comment: Definitely, @dariosicily, appreciate your help.  I got as far as realizing I could edit the pom.xml file but thought to only go that route if I had installed a Neo4j Server on my laptop; I'm using the Neo4j Desktop and it's advertised that all you have to do is click on "Install neosemantics" and you should be good-to-go.  The whole point of the package is to be able to import RDF so you'd think I wouldn't have to configure Maven to get the software to perform its basic job. Customer support was no help. Maybe I'll try to configure the server embedded in the Desktop.  I'm just cursed.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, fyi I checked [pom.xml](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/5.1/pom.xml) and `jackson 2.13` is present (not sure if it is referring to neo4j Desktop).